# JQuery select and remove all ps that are not in a certain div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, I have a pretty complicated html setup here, and in my function I need to remove all the ps (NOT just all divs, ps specifically) that are NOT within these 2 subclasses : `.panel-heading` and `.panel-body`

Originally I got all ps in the following:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">

    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingEight">

        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseNine2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseNine2">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>
                <span style="margin-left: 12px; display: inline-block;"></span>AirWatch and Workspace ONE
            </a>   
        </h4>

    </div>

    <div id="collapseNine2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingEight">

        <div class="panel-body">
```

with this:

```
$(labArr[i].selector).find(".panel-default").find("p").remove()
```

And this works except its deleting literally all the ps, which I can't have. I know I need to use the not selector so Ive tried:

```
$(labArr[i].selector).find(".panel-default").find("div:not(.panel-body, .panel-heading)").remove();
```

and

```
$(labArr[i].selector).find(".panel-default:not(.panel-body, .panel-heading)").find("p").remove();
```

which did not work. I don't know why.

How can I remove ALL ps in panel-default except the ones in those 2 classes?

Comment: The problem is you don't have any `<p>` tags in your sample html

Comment: I append them to the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always with selectors, there's lots of different ways to achieve the same thing, but try this:

```
$(labArr[i].selector).find(".panel-default p").not(function() {
    return $(this).closest('.panel-body, .panel-heading').length;
}).remove();
```

That inspects each paragraph matched, then discards any that live under an element with the two prohibited classes.